# Adding new key(s) to enable partitioning, INSERT performance?

Tags: mysql, performance, index, partitioning, insert

I have a table to storage GPS coordinates with multiple (~30) inserts per second (from 50 different devices)  during 12 hours per day, so the table is growing fast, to improve the SELECT speed I was thinking of create a partition in the table by Date or DeviceID.

In that case I will need to add the partitioning keys as primary keys?, how will that affect the insertion performance?

```
CREATE TABLE `carlocation` (
  `Id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `Date` datetime DEFAULT NULL,  
  `GpsLatitude` double DEFAULT NULL,
  `GpsLongitude` double DEFAULT NULL,
  `DeviceID` int(11) NOT NULL,  
  PRIMARY KEY (`Id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

The server is a Dual Core Xeon with 2GB RAM.
Thanks.

**Update:** The queries are like

```
SELECT *
FROM carlocation
 WHERE ((carlocation.DeviceID = 2) AND (carlocation.Date> '2010-01-01') AND (carlocation.Date< '2010-01-02'))
```

Always quering for ONE device only, in one or multiple days.

Comment: Very much depends on how your typical query looks like.  Could you tell us?

Comment: True, updated question.

Answer (score 1):

Your one select needs this "compound" index.

```
INDEX(DeviceID, Date)
```

Do you have other queries?

But your question was about PARTITIONing.  No advantage, based on what you have said so far.